# I put cron job command on cPanel but it is not working

Tags: php, laravel, cron, cpanel

The put the following command on the cPanel cron job

```
php /home/talal1993/public_html/manage/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

But it is not working.
When I run the command on the terminal it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you might be trying to create some command such as:

```
1   *   *   *   *   /usr/bin/php /home/talal1993/public_html/manage/artisan.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

which your timing goes in the first part:

```
*   *   *   *   *
```